# Multiple joins chose latest record by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to link four tables (3 of them key to this question). I need to pull the latest payment type used from T16. T16 links to T17 via headerid, which links to A10 via pledgeid.

I have tried this a bunch of different ways. The code below is giving me the latest date for each payment type, but what I really want is just the last payment type.

[image: Examples]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A10.RecordId
    ,A10.AccountNumber
    ,A01.FamilyId
    ,a01.FamilyMemberType
    ,A10.PledgeCode  --Child Number
    ,A10.OriginalPledgeId
    ,A10.PledgeId
    ,A01.FirstName
    ,A01.LastName
    ,A10.PledgeStatus
    ,A10.AmountPerGift
    ,A10.PledgeFrequency
    ,t16.PaymentType
FROM 
    A10_AccountPledges A10
LEFT JOIN
    A01_AccountMaster A01 ON a01.AccountNumber = a10.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN
    T17_RecurringDonations T17 ON T17.PledgeId = A10.PledgeId
LEFT JOIN
    T16_RecurringTransactionHeaders T16 ON T16.HeaderId = T17.HeaderId
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         T17.pledgeID
         ,MAX(T16.LastUsedDate) as lastdate
     FROM 
         T17_RecurringDonations T17
     LEFT JOIN
         T16_RecurringTransactionHeaders T16 ON T16.HeaderId = T17.HeaderId
     GROUP BY
         T17.pledgeID) pm ON pm.PledgeId = A10.PledgeId --and pm.lastdate = T16.LastUsedDate
WHERE 
    A01.[Status] = 'A'
    AND a10.PledgeId = 398353 --test case
```

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like below:

```
select top 1 *
from (
    YOUR QUERY HERE
)
order by lastdate desc;
```

Notes:

- YOUR QUERY HERE is a placeholder which will hold your whole query as a subquery
- you need to add the selection of `lastdate` to your subselect in order to make sure you can `order by lastdate desc`

EDIT

As @spaindc explained, this idea was applied, resulting in

```
   SELECT distinct 
       A10.AccountNumber
      ,A01.FamilyId
      ,a01.FamilyMemberType
      ,A10.PledgeCode  --Child Number
      ,A10.OriginalPledgeId
      ,A10.PledgeId
      ,A01.FirstName
      ,A01.LastName
      ,A10.PledgeStatus
      ,A10.PledgeFrequency
      ,(SELECT top 1 T16.PaymentType
          FROM T16_RecurringTransactionHeaders T16, T17_RecurringDonations T17
          where T16.HeaderId = T17.HeaderId
          and T17.PledgeId = A10.PledgeId
          order by t16.LastUsedDate desc
        ) as PaymentType
      FROM A10_AccountPledges A10
      left join A01_AccountMaster A01 on a01.AccountNumber = a10.AccountNumber
      where A01.[Status] = 'A'
```

Comment: This worked! See below for revised code

Comment: @spaindc thanks, edited my answer, adding the code you have ended up writing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lajos for correct answer. Here is the final code for reference.

```
   SELECT distinct 
       A10.AccountNumber
      ,A01.FamilyId
      ,a01.FamilyMemberType
      ,A10.PledgeCode  --Child Number
      ,A10.OriginalPledgeId
      ,A10.PledgeId
      ,A01.FirstName
      ,A01.LastName
      ,A10.PledgeStatus
      ,A10.PledgeFrequency
      ,(SELECT top 1 T16.PaymentType
          FROM T16_RecurringTransactionHeaders T16, T17_RecurringDonations T17
          where T16.HeaderId = T17.HeaderId
          and T17.PledgeId = A10.PledgeId
          order by t16.LastUsedDate desc
        ) as PaymentType
      FROM A10_AccountPledges A10
      left join A01_AccountMaster A01 on a01.AccountNumber = a10.AccountNumber
      where A01.[Status] = 'A'
```